# Dynamically creating WebViews and TextViews in a LinearLayout only whenever adding one

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to dynamically create web views and text areas within a linear view that is inside a scroll view like a news feed. Not sure if this is the best method but basically I want to dynamically load json items and render in a news feed. When my code runs it only renders one item and I'm not sure why its not creating them all.

I'm learning android trying to figure out how to dynamically retrieve and display data that is essentially a wall feed.

I'm having issues when I try to create a webview or a text view inside of a linear view which is inside of a scroll view it either writes over the existing object as it loops or everything is sitting on top of its self. I'm not honestly quite sure, im extremely green to android development.

Summary:

Problem 1: This code doesn't create dynamic elements and stack them inside the scroll view so I can scroll through them. 
Problem 2: How do I set a default size for each item so they will be the same size in the scroll view?
Problem 3: The simulated device I'm using doesn't have access to the internet. I'm using a proxy to loop back to my PC to the local api that is running that returns the json string. It can't load the youtube embed when their are links, and I can't load in browser either.

Any help is appreciated.

sample json

```
{
  "4006": {
    "owner": "freedomhard", 
    "post_data": "Cheers.", 
    "time": 1570588719
  }, 
  "4009": {
    "owner": "Kcreichen", 
    "post_data": "Good night &amp;#x1f60a;", 
    "time": 1570589506
  }, 
  "4011": {
    "owner": "Jpowers40828", 
    "post_data": "Instead people revere them as celebrities and impressive.", 
    "time": 1570590300
  }, 
  "4024": {
    "owner": "NorthernMich", 
    "post_data": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/R6E1H82DqHE", 
    "time": 1570593697
  }, 
  "4027": {
    "owner": "DvlDog17", 
    "post_data": "&amp;#x1f918;&amp;#x1f918;\r\n\r\nhttps://youtu.be/ptro0vwRMaA", 
    "time": 1570595894
  }, 
  "4037": {
    "owner": "617Dan", 
    "post_data": "https://www.facebook.com/1230804746996245/posts/2530952203648153?sfns=mo\r\n\r\n\r\nCame across this little bit this morning, sums it up quite nicely", 
    "time": 1570617231
  }, 
  "4045": {
    "owner": "billyd1431", 
    "post_data": "https://www.lovedreamer.com/Sophia-Rossi-Big-Boob-Doll", 
    "time": 1570625995
  }, 
  "4047": {
    "owner": "txangelnjs", 
    "post_data": "Good morning y&amp;#039;all!!", 
    "time": 1570626060
  }, 
  "4048": {
    "owner": "freedomhard", 
    "post_data": "Hello you sexy mother fuckers.", 
    "time": 1570626409
  }, 
  "4052": {
    "owner": "Jpowers40828", 
    "post_data": "It\ufffds because he\ufffds not a conservative, he\ufffds a liberal who doesn\ufffdt respect the 2nd amendment and loves social programs (look at bailout programs). \r\nhttps://www.newsweek.com/trump-deficit-debt-cbo-data-obama-1463802", 
    "time": 1570628450
  }, 
  "4053": {
    "owner": "Otterbox92", 
    "post_data": "Celebrating three years sober from alcohol today! &amp;#x1f642; looking back, I\ufffdm thankful and blessed that I got that DUI. It completely changed me and I haven\ufffdt had a sip since that night.", 
    "time": 1570628462
  }
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/news_update"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="673dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">


        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.freedomhard_test;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONObject.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.util.Base64;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView newtext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "http://10.0.2.3";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                final String stack_trace = e.toString();
                TextView newtextz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
                newtextz.setText(stack_trace);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_view);
                            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                mainObject = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                                System.out.println(mainObject);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                //some exception handler code.
                            }finally {
                                if(mainObject != null){
                                    Iterator<String> iter = mainObject.keys();
                                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                                        String key = iter.next();
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject value = mainObject.getJSONObject(key);
                                            String post_data = value.getString("post_data");
                                            String user = value.getString("owner");
                                            String time = value.getString("time");
                                            String new_text = "\n" + user + " - " + post_data + " - " + time;
                                            if(post_data.contains("youtube")){

                                                TextView newTxt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                                newTxt.setText(new_text);
                                                relativeLayout.addView(newTxt);

                                                WebView webView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
                                                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                                                String unencodedHtml =
                                                        "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/GAdGmJxfcf8' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
                                                String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes(),
                                                        Base64.NO_PADDING);
                                                webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
                                                webView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                                                relativeLayout.addView(webView);
                                            }else{
                                                TextView newTxt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                                                newTxt.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                                                newTxt.setText(new_text);
                                            }

                                            //newtext.setText(new_text);

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // Something went wrong!
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }



        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
Instead creating this views, you should use RecyclerView for this.

now, if you really want to create views programatically of that way, then you should do something like this.

```
WebView wv = new WebView(context);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewWidth,ViewHight);
params./*add required params here*/;
wv.setLayoutParams(params);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);


/*you should take care of hierarchy adding view depending on your layout 
orientation*/
YourLinearLayoutToAddView.addView(wv);
YourLinearLayoutToAddView.addView(tv);
```

Comment: can you give me an example of Recycler View? I am super new I want to do it the proper way.